# How to parse a here-string in PowerShell as a hash?

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, hash, text-processing

[This example](https://www.educba.com/powershell-here-string/) is easy enough:

```
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $hash = @"
>> Name = Jackson
>> Employer = BigData
>> EmpID = 2032
>> Type = Permanent
>> "@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $hash
Name = Jackson
Employer = BigData
EmpID = 2032
Type = Permanent
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $hash | ConvertFrom-StringData

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Employer                       BigData
Type                           Permanent
EmpID                          2032
Name                           Jackson


PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
```

Which is excellent and the desired output.  Here:

```
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> cat .\hash.txt
$hash = @"
Name = Jackson
Employer = BigData
EmpID = 2032
Type = Permanent
"@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $foo = Get-Content .\hash.txt
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc> $foo
$hash = @"
Name = Jackson
Employer = BigData
EmpID = 2032
Type = Permanent
"@
PS C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc>
```

the data originates in a file.  How is this file read as a here-string so that it can be [used](https://powershellmagazine.com/2014/09/09/using-the-convertfrom-string-cmdlet-to-parse-structured-text/) as above?

Comment: To read it as a single *multi-line string*, append `-Raw` to your `Get-Content`. Could also use: `${C:\Users\saunders\Desktop\misc\hash.txt} | ConvertFrom-StringData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.\hash.txt` is *in effect* a `.ps1` script file, so you could change its extension an then load it via `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-), at which point `$hash` will be defined and can be passed to [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata).

To process the file as-is, you can pass its content to [`Invoke-Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-expression) (though note that this cmdlet [should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375)):

```bash
Invoke-Expression (Get-Content -Raw t.txt)
$hash | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

---

If you have control over how `.\hash.txt` gets created and can change its name, you can save it as a *PowerShell data file*, i.e. with extension `.psd1`, which can be read as-is with the [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile) cmdlet:

A `.psd1` file is in effect the source-code representation of a [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) literal, whose syntax requirements are more stringent than for *text* that can be parsed with `ConvertFrom-StringData`:

```bash
# Save the source-code representation of a hashtable literal
# to a file - do NOT include a variable assignment:
@'
@{
  Name = 'Jackson'
  Employer = 'BigData'
  EmpID = 2032
  Type = 'Permanent'
}
'@ > hash.psd1

Import-PowerShellDataFile hash.psd1
```

---

As an aside:

- As of PowerShell 7.3.2, both `ConvertFrom-StringData` and `Import-PowerShellData` do *not* preserve the entries *in definition order*, given that `[hasthable]` instances are inherently unordered.
- [GitHub issue #19070](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/19070) proposes overcoming this limitation, by making these cmdlets return *ordered* hashtables instead, via [`System.Management.Automation.OrderedHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.OrderedHashtable), which derives from `[hashtable]`.

Comment: many pluses and huge amount of info.  Cannot thank you enough.  Excellent context for your provided answer.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped, @NicholasSaunders; my pleasure. I appreciate the nice feedback.

Comment: Yes, I had to try it out!  This works quite well on Linux.  In this situation, it was more about context and terminology.  I tried searching for "@" and "`" with powershell but couldn't figure it out.